# Incomplete (abandoned) event registrations

Tags: civievent

Is there a way to capture those who fill out the event registration form, hit continue, but then do not hit continue on the confirmation page? I thought it used to do this, but noticed today that either I was remembering wrong or it has stopped doing this.

Essentially the folks I'm working with want people to have the pay later option without ever showing them that option. Too many people pick that rather than just paying now and then they forget to pay. But some government organizations and such need to do an invoice. So they want to capture the ones only partially submitted as being incomplete so they can then update them when the payment comes in.

They have the information on the confirmation page that you should pay via Paypal, but if you can't, here's how to do it. If you click Continue, it then takes you to Paypal.

Answer (score 1):

CiviCRM doesn't store data that has been partially submitted. If your form uses paypal standard payment method and user fills in the other details and pay's now then he will be taken to paypal screen where he will need to enter card details or pay using paypal account. Before going to Paypal CiviCRM creates Pending Participant records and then changes status to completed if it receives payment.

So you will need to either have registrants submit 3 step form or build extension that would do one of the following

1. Don't use confirmation page incase for Pay later and/or Pay now.
2. Store Data in CiviCRM when user submits the main form, Truncate if user submits confirmation, Add report to list all the user that submitted partially.

(#1 will be simple and #2 will need more work)

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: It's just too bad that it doesn't do this. Most systems do, as then you can contact those who abandoned the process and can see if they need assistance or anything.